# Testing Private Social Network Capacity

Tags: ubuntu, performance-testing, lamp

I've set up a private social network (humhub) on localhost (127.0.0.1) and I was I am interested in finding how many users can use this resource simultaneously. I am testing this out on my own pc, but I intend to use this on a shared server and I don't want to interfere with other people's work. For the time being, I wanted to know what sort of methods there are to do this. I am willing to code, but if there were a ready made script hanging around somewhere online that would also be perfect. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

If my question is vague, please tell me how I can improve it, or if I need to add information.

Also, here is the website of the software in use. It's sitting on a LAMP stack on Ubuntu.

Comment: You can check out https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it seems interesting. Is there any way to use this program to send more requests than the server can handle? In other words, instead of just benchmarking, can I send requests until the server starts to lag?